# Como usar a função tablaStack no R

Tags: r

Boa noite meu professor de Bioestatística esta ensinando a usar o R, ele passou o seguinte questão

(Construir tabelas de frequências da RAÇA, ESTADO CIVIL e ESCOLARIDADE. Identifique quais são as categorias dessas variáveis que se destacam, faça a separação por ano. (Dica: utilize o comando `tableStack` do pacote `epiDisplay`. Utilize o ANO como variável que vai cruzar com todas as outras).

Mas por mais que tente sempre da erro. Alguém pode me ajudar com essa questão?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
utilizando essa foto como banco de dados

Comment: Bem-vindo ao stack overflow. Qual comando você está tentando? E qual a mensagem de erro? Veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) algumas dicas de como melhorar sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Seria legal você colocar o código que você está utilizando e a mensagem de erro que aparece. 
Veja se o código abaixo responde a sua dúvida

```
library(epiDisplay)
dados <- data.frame(
  Num = 1:3, DIASEMANA = c("DOM", "DOM", "DOM"),
  DIA_obito = c(01,01,01), MES_obito = c("JAN", "JAN", "JAN"),
  ANO_obito = c(2006,2006,2006), 
  CLASSE_hora_obito = c("00:00 a 05:59", "00:00 a 05:59", "00:00 a 05:59"),
  IDADE_se_vivo = c(40,42,29), IDADE = c(32,34,20), 
  SEXO = c("M", "F", "M"), RACACOR = c(4,4,4), ESTCIV = c(2,2,1),
  ESC = c(5,5,4), LOCOCOR = c("Via publica", "Via publica", "Hospital"),
  BAIACOR = c("PONTA NEGRA", "PONTA NEGRA", "ADRIANOPOLIS"),
  ENDOCOR = c("ESTRADA DA PONTA NEG", "ESTRADA DA PONTA NEG", "RUA RECIFE"),
  CLASSE_CB = c("OUTROS ATT", "OUTROS ATT", "OUTROS ATT"))
tableStack(RACACOR:ESC, dados)
```